# java performing array calculation

Tags: java

The code below will print two square matrices and I need them to perform multiplication between the two matrices but i cant seem to get that part working. I put a comment right before that block of code where the problem is. But for now all it prints is zeros. Iv been looking online at a lot of sites but cant seem to get mine to work.

```
 import java.util.*;
    import java.math.*;

    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create the grid
        final int rowWidth = 9;
        final int colHeight = 9;

        Random rand = new Random();

        int [][] board = new int [rowWidth][colHeight];

        //fill the grid
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {

            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {

                board[row][col] = rand.nextInt(10);
            }
        }

        //display output
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

            for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {

                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
                //System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

                System.out.println();


                int [][] board2 = new int [rowWidth][colHeight];

        //fill the grid
        for (int row2 = 0; row2 < board2.length; row2++) {

            for (int col2 = 0; col2 < board[row2].length; col2++) {

                board[row2][col2] = rand.nextInt(10);
            }
        }

        //display output
        for(int m = 0; m < board2.length; m++) {

            for(int n = 0; n < board[m].length; n++) {

                System.out.print(board[m][n] + " ");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    //error is somewhere here

          int[][] calculationMultiplication = new int[rowWidth][colHeight];
      for (int l = 0; l < rowWidth; l++) {
          for (int t = 0; t < colHeight; t++) {
              for (int z = 0; z < rowWidth; z++) {
                calculationMultiplication[l][t] = calculationMultiplication[l][t] + board[l][z] * board2[z][t];
              }
          }
      }    

    //display output

      System.out.println("\nProduct of the 2 matrices is ");
      for (int i = 0; i < calculationMultiplication.length; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < calculationMultiplication[0].length; j++) {
              System.out.print(calculationMultiplication[i][j] + " ");
          }
          System.out.println();
      }

    } //end of main
    } //end of class Main
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Also, what's "perform a multi"?

Comment: multiplication and its running but it is printing zeros

Comment: OK. Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: No I did not, im not sure how.

Comment: Google "<insert_your_IDE_here> debugger". Learning to debug programs is an *incredibly* important skill that all programmers should learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've not filled the `board2` array, so all its elements will be `0`. In the `for` loop, you should also assign random values to `board2`. You are doing it twice for the `board` array.

```
//fill the grid
for (int row2 = 0; row2 < board2.length; row2++) {
    for (int col2 = 0; col2 < board2[row2].length; col2++) { // notice 'board2[row].length'
        board2[row2][col2] = rand.nextInt(10);
    }
}
```

You should do something similar in the `for` loops where you display the array:

```
//display output
for (int m = 0; m < board2.length; m++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < board2[m].length; n++) { // notice 'board2[row].length'
        System.out.print(board2[m][n] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: That isn't even everything.... Looks like a rather bad case of copy/paste programming to me. `board[row2]` in the inner loop guard should be `board2[row2]` (I think)

Comment: @user3580294 not sure what you are trying to say. Do you mean the for that displays the `board2` content?

Comment: `for (int n = 0; n < board[m].length; n++) {` should be `for (int n = 0; n < board2[m].length; n++) {`, I think. Doesn't make a difference in this case, since the matrices are the same size, but I don't think that was intended code. I was probably misusing terminology... My apologies. Meant the termination condition for the loop.

Comment: You are right, edited!

Answer (score 1):

`board2` is always zero.

You fill the wrong array here:

```
//fill the grid
        for (int row2 = 0; row2 < board2.length; row2++) {

            for (int col2 = 0; col2 < board[row2].length; col2++) {

                board[row2][col2] = rand.nextInt(10);
            }
        }
```

Comment: "always `null`"? You might want to reword that...

Comment: @user3580294 Sorry i have corected my post it is always 0

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just did simple copy paste mistakes that can be avoidable if you used methods. I'll tell you how but first here's how you can discover your mistake:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%d * %d = %d",board[l][z], board2[z][t], board[l][z] * board2[z][t]));
```

Add this just before doing the calculation for `calculationMultiplication[l][t]`. Try if you want...

Anyway getting back to your mistakes, you have populated your first matrix only, the second one contain zeros (verify your code in the for loop for inserting random numbers into the second matrix), therefore any number multiplied by zero is equal to zero.

I haven't looked at all your code, because it contain a lot of copy paste which confused you and could confuse any one as well, so here's a better way to avoid mistakes in printing the matrix and inserting random numbers:

**Printing:**

```
void printMatrix(int[][] matrix){
   for(int row =0; row < numOfRows; row++){
      for(int col =0; col < numOfCols; col++){
        System.out.print(matrix[row][col]+" ");
      }
      System.out.println(); // new line
   }
}
```

**Inserting:**

```
void insertMatrix(int[][] matrix){
    for(int row =0; row < numOfRows; row++){
      for(int col =0; col < numOfCols; col++){
        matrix[row][col] = rand.nextInt(10); // rand must be declared outside any method
      }
   }
}
```

**Putting all together:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    // create the grid
    final static int rowWidth = 9;
    final static int colHeight = 9;
    static Random rand;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rand = new Random();
        int[][] board = new int[rowWidth][colHeight];
        int[][] board2 = new int[rowWidth][colHeight];
        int[][] calculationMultiplication = new int[rowWidth][colHeight];

        // fill
        insertMatrxi(board);

        // display output
        printMatrix(board);

        System.out.println();

        // fill
        insertMatrxi(board2);

        // display output
        printMatrix(board2);

        for (int l = 0; l < rowWidth; l++) {
            for (int t = 0; t < colHeight; t++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < rowWidth; z++) {
                    calculationMultiplication[l][t] += board[l][z] * board2[z][t];
                }
            }
        }

        // display output
        System.out.println("\nProduct of the 2 matrices is ");
        printMatrix(calculationMultiplication);

    } // end of main

    public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int row = 0; row < rowWidth; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < colHeight; col++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(); // new line
        }
    }

    public static void insertMatrxi(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int row = 0; row < rowWidth; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < colHeight; col++) {
                matrix[row][col] = rand.nextInt(10);
            }
        }
    }
} // end of class Main
```